# How to differentiate between "a string" and "a actual code" in python?

Tags: python, parsing, instrumentation

My works relates to instrumentation of code fragments in python code. So in my work i would be writing a script in python such that I take another python file as input and insert any necessary code in the required place with my script.

The following code is a sample code of a file which i would be instrumenting:

```
A.py #normal un-instrumented code

statements
....
....

def move(self,a):
    statements
    ......
    print "My function is defined" 
    ......

statements 
......
```

My script what actually does is to check each lines in the A.py and if there is a "def" then a code fragment is instrumented on top of the code the def function

The following example is how the final out put should be:

```
A.py #instrumented code

statements
....
....

@decorator    #<------ inserted code
def move(self,a):
    statements
    ......
    print "My function is defined" 
    ......

statements 
......
```

But I have been resulted with different output. The following code is the final output which i am getting:

A.py #instrumented code

```
statements
....
....

@decorator    #<------ inserted code
def move(self,a):
    statements
    ......
    @decorator #<------ inserted code [this should not occur]
    print "My function is defined" 
    ......

statements 
......
```

I can understand that in the instrumented code it recognizes "def" in the word "defined" and so it instruments the a code above it.

In realty the instrumented code has lots of these problems I was not able to properly instrument the given python file. Is there any other way to differentiate the actual "def" from string?

Thank you

Comment: How are you finding `def` in the instrumentation?  If using a Regular Expresssion then try `r'\bdef\b'`.  The `\b` marks a word boundary.

Comment: Will it work even when there is a statement like this print" This is a def"

Comment: no.  To deal with text embedded in quotes you will need negative look-arounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ast` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) to parse the file properly.

This code prints the line number and column offset of each `def` statement:

```
import ast
with open('mymodule.py') as f:
    tree = ast.parse(f.read())
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
        print node.lineno, node.col_offset
```

Comment: How do i use the column offset value when i am instrumenting a statement above the def function so that its is aligned correctly as the def function.

Comment: @karthik I'm not sure how tab characters affect `col_offset`; try it out. I think you need to copy `col_offset` characters from beginning of the line and use that string to indent `@decorator`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regular Expression.  To avoid `def` inside quotes then you can use negative look-arounds:

```
import re

for line in open('A.py'):
    m = re.search(r"(?!<[\"'])\bdef\b(?![\"'])", line)
    if m:
        print r'@decorator    #<------ inserted code' 

    print line
```

However, there might be other occurances of `def` that you or I can't think of, and if we are not careful we end-up writing the Python parser all over again.  @Janne Karila's suggestion of using `ast.parse` is probably safer in the long term.

Comment: Then there are multi-line strings.

Comment: @JanneKarila: yup, that's one I didn't think of.  Which only goes to show that your answer is preferred.