# How to differentiate between actual code and strings for the purpose of instrumentation in python?

Tags: python, parsing, scripting, instrumentation

My objective is to instrument a file with few code fragments. There is particular challenge that i am facing while instrumentation i would like to explain with a scenario.

```
 #A.py   
    #start of the code 

    from future import division

    import os
    .....
    ....
    print "from future import division"
    ....

    #end of the code
```

I will be writing a code instrumentation.py where i will be instrumenting few statements at the start of the file #A.py. But due to some reason "from future import division" statement should always come first in a python file. So to instrument I would be searching for a string "from future import division" in the file and when ever I find it i would instrument after that line. The following scenario shows it.

```
 #A.py   
    #start of the code 

    from future import division
    print " i successfully instrumented"  <------ #inserted code
    import os
    .....
    ....
    print "from future import division"
    ....

    #end of the code
```

But instead i get a scenario like this :

```
   #A.py  

    #start of the code 

    from future import division
    print " i successfully instrumented"  <------ #inserted code
    import os
    .....
    ....
    print "from future import division"
    print " i successfully instrumented"  <------ #inserted code
    ....

    #end of the code
```

My search algorithm couldnt differentiate between an actual code or a string. I would like to know in general how could you differentiate between a string and a actual code?

```
#instrumentation.py
#start of the code 
p=open("A.py",'r')
parser=p.readlines()

while(i<len(parser)):
    if("from" and "future" and "import" and "division" in parser[i]):
         # I will insert a code fragment in the i+1 position
....
....

#End of the code
```

My search algorithm is shown in the above scenario.

Comment: It's not clear at all, to me at least, what you mean by "instrumenting", thus it is really difficult to understand what you are trying to do and how to fix it. Also, could you please describe your search algorithm so we know what you've already tried?

Comment: @Brandon Invergo Inserting code fragments in the specific lines in a file to observe the working

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't familiar with that concept. I'm [reading about it now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_(computer_programming)). Sorry for the noise!

Comment: Strings are surrounding by single or double quotes? And yes, if a string spans multiple lines, you'll have to keep track of the quotes.

Comment: Wait, what, you [already asked this question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809248/how-to-differentiate-between-a-string-and-a-actual-code-in-python) and got an accept answer? What's different here?

Comment: @Evert The difference is that i have used a python parser in the earlier case to so check for the occurrence of a method. Since i use a python parser it parses the entire file and can understand which are function and which are not. But in this case " from future import division" is not recognized in python parser.

Comment: For completeness sake: the correct statement is `from __future__ import ...`; there are more `from __future__` import options, do not just look for `division`. The import has to be done *early* because it influences how the compiler treats the remainder of the module.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters that is very good remark. So my search algorithm would restrict to only "from" and "__future__".

Comment: When I run your 3 lines through `ast`, I find an `ast.ImportFrom` node, which is exactly your `from __future__ import division` line. You could then eg use the line number to verify it contains "from" and "future". So I don't understand what you mean by "is not recognized".

Comment: @Evert I think you might be right. I will try it my self and let you know.